# How I can prove that for any natural number $n$ such that $30<n$, $\pi(4n-3)<n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I need to proove that for any natural number $n>30$:

$$\pi(4n-3)<n.$$

In this inequality, $\pi(x):\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is the defined as follows:
$$\pi(x):=Card(\lbrace p \ | \ p\leq x\ \ s.t \ \ p \ \ is\ \ prime\rbrace ).$$
Plot:
ListPlot[Table[i - PrimePi[4 i - 3], {i, 31, 200}]]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXHzD.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: That definition defines a set.  If $x = 12$ then $\pi(x) =\{2,3,7,11\}$.  Did you mean $\pi(x) = \max Set$?

Comment: .... that wouldn't make sense $\pi(4*31 - 3)$ would be much more than 31.  Did you $\pi(x) = $ order of Set?

Comment: No, $\pi(12)=5$. The number of prime number less than $12$.

Comment: it is true, we have [$\pi(x)<1.3\frac{x}{\log x}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) for $x\leq 17$

Comment: I try to proof it by induction but I  cant...

Comment: 1/2 the numbers are divisible by 2.   1/3 by 3.  1/5 by 5.  1/7 by 7.  This leaves on average .22  of the numbers relatively prime to 2,3,5,7.  The difficulty is figuring out the exact modulo.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from $2$, $3$, $5$ and $7$, every prime number must be relatively prime to $210$. Between $1$ and $210$, there are $\varphi(210) = 48$ numbers prime to $210$. Whether a number is relatively prime to $210$ depends only on its remainder modulo $210$. Therefore for all $k \geq 1$, we have $\pi(210k) \leq 48k + 4$.

For any number $n \geq 1$, there is some number $k$ such that $4n -3 \leq 210k \leq 4n + 206$. Thus for $n \geq 597$ we have
$$\pi(4n - 3) \leq \pi(210k) \leq 48k + 4 \leq \frac{48}{210}(4n + 206) + 4< n.$$

Now it is enough to check the inequality for $31 \leq n \leq 596$.

Comment: Where did the 550 come from?

Comment: The inequality $(48/210)(4n + 206) + 4< n$ is valid only when $n \geq 597$.

Comment: Oh, the very last one? Maybe it would be clearer to state the other three inequalities and then say "and, for $n \geq 550$, ...".